# FPDF error: Unable to create output file:

Tags: php

While saving file, following error is being encountered

> FPDF error: Unable to create output file: /var/www/html/xyz/xyz/pdf/21951.pdf

I have set permission to 777

My code is

```
$file_name = $filePath.$invoice . '.pdf';
$fileatt = $pdf->Output($file_name, 'F');
```

Comment: show your full code..

Answer (score 0):

Here you should make sure you have the permission of the **full** path, and the path exists. You'll get this error, when either is not matched.